# GUI option for adding new folder in Gnome even if Nautilus is not full of items

Tags: nautilus, ubuntu-gnome, wayland

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome on Wayland. Today I needed to ad a folder to my Home directory and I couldn't find a simple way to do it in Nautilus. Eventually I remembered the "Control + Shift + N" option and that worked.

What has happened to the GUI options for this everyday task?

Edit: I found the answer. The "Add folder" option is now an icon, in the top left of the pull down menu.

[image]

Comment: Both "new folder" and "show hidden files" are still there in the hamburger menu.

Comment: I just found them and edited my answer. I hadn't noticed that "Add new folder" had been replaced by an icon

Comment: That's a solution, should not be added to the question IMO. Instead please click the "this solves my problem" button. Adding "even if Nautilus is not full of items" doesn't actually make it a different question.

Comment: I changed the title because you asked me to edit my question to show it wasn't a duplicate. Where is the "this solves my problem" button?

Comment: I **never** asked you to edit anything, and sorry, but it's a duplicate. You killed the "this solves my problem" button by choosing to edit instead of clicking it.

Comment: @pomsky You, or someone from Ask Ubuntu, wrote "Please edit your question to show it is not a duplicate of "Simple way to create a folder when nautilus file list is full of items"

Comment: That's not completely true, the system showed you a "this solves my problem" button **and** the "Please edit your question..." **if you think it's not duplicate**. You chose to edit and add a solution identical to some answers posted to the proposed duplicate to the question itself and rolled back the formatting improvements made to the question by me in the process.